# How to have "and" and "or" conditions in jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to check if two separate divs are returning true with hasClass.

```
    if($('#first-name, #last-name').hasClass('has-focused')) {
        $('#personal-info').valid();
    }
```

This checks if either one has class 'has-focused'.

Instead I could do something like this:

```
    if($('#first-name').hasClass('has-focused')&&$('#last-name').hasClass('has-focused')) {
        $('#personal-info').valid();
    }
```

However, that solution feels a bit clumsy. So is it possible to do something like this.

```
    if($('#first-name'&&'#last-name').hasClass('has-focused')) {
        $('#personal-info').valid();
    }
```

Comment: No way.. $('#first-name'&&'#last-name').hasClass('has-focused') can't be done

Comment: `$('#first-name, #last-name').not('.has-focused').length==0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that, though you can have a filter based solution like

```
if ($('#first-name, #last-name').not('.has-focused').length == 0) {
  $('#personal-info').valid();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
$('#first-name.has-focused,#last-name.has-focused').length === 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter for the class name and length property to check if both have the class

```
if ($('#first-name, #last-name').filter(".has-focused").length == 2){
  $('#personal-info').valid();
}
```